# disable textbox till datatables get populated in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I am getting data to datatable through ajax call and i am having trouble in disabling a text-box till my datatable get populated(either zero results or more results.)
This is my datatable:

```
tableIsasSchedulesDetailView = $('#tableIsasSchedules').DataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "deferRender": true,
                "bServerSide": false,
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                ajax: "/services/json/schedule.aspx?t=is&df=" + date + "&pfjson=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(filters)),
"aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "Clientid", "bVisible": false, "sTitle": "", "mData": "Clientid", "sClass": "CellS", "sWidth": "0" },
                    { "sName": "DisplayName", "sTitle": "Client", "mData": "Displayname", "sClass": "CellS Cell125" }],
"fnInitComplete":
"fnCreatedRow":
"fnRowCallback":
});}
```

This is my text-box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to disable this text-box till i get data from ajax call(datatable gets populated).
I tried disabling it:
$('#Date').prop('disabled',true); 
i called this on the first line of javascript function that calls to load my datatable. But it is not making any change. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable the textbox by default, and then enable in `fnDrawCallback`.  So you would render your input as:

```
<input type="TextBox" ID="Date" disabled="disabled" />
```

Then in your datatable initialisation:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
    $('#Date').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

This gets called after every reload of data, so you would have to have something to reapply the disabled attribute if that's the behaviour you're after.  You should also be aware of the page lifecycle, if the javascript runs before the page is fully loaded then that might explain your js disabling issue.  Have you got the datatables code in a `$(document).ready()` block?

Also, these's something strange in your code: You are populating the datatable using ajax, yet you have `"bServerSide": false,`.